# A Good 3D Engine for Simulating an AI Car?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, simulation, game-engine

I'm trying to build a car which can drive itself using video frames from an Android camera on-board using Neural networks. I haven't bought the hardware (car + android).

Meanwhile, I want to simulate the driver application (on my laptop) by streaming video frames from a 3D simulator and see if works properly.

What's an easy-to-learn and mostly pre-configured engine for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no easy-way to do that. In our robotic laboratory we use [**ROS**](http://www.ros.org/wiki/) to do this type of simulations.

It includes a 3D simulator (Gazebo), camera and sensor simulation and a lot of other stuff. You can see an example of 3D robot/camera simulation in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8z_rJyEVZg).

Unfortunately ROS is not easy-to-learn and there is no complete documentation.

Another possibility is to use **Blender** (the open source, cross platform suite of tools for 3D). There are some robotic project that use Blender (you can see [this page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community%3aScience/Robotics) for more info) but I have no personal experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [V-Rep](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/), even though its a commercial product its much superior  in performance. It has built in models for autonomous cars. If you are from India, contact  [Asimov Robotics](http://asimovrobotics.com/), they are the resellers

Answer (score 0):

To update this answer for 2017, Gazebo appears to be one of the leading 3D Simulation engines available today. Definitely worth looking into for this kind of application.

An excerpt from their home page:

> Robot simulation is an essential tool in every roboticist's toolbox. A
>   well-designed simulator makes it possible to rapidly test algorithms,
>   design robots, perform regression testing, and train AI system using
>   realistic scenarios. Gazebo offers the ability to accurately and
>   efficiently simulate populations of robots in complex indoor and
>   outdoor environments. At your fingertips is a robust physics engine,
>   high-quality graphics, and convenient programmatic and graphical
>   interfaces. Best of all, Gazebo is free with a vibrant community.

http://gazebosim.org/

Also, the game Grand Theft Auto has been used to test self driving car algorithms. There are APIs to do everything from change the pedestrian traffic, to lights, to weather and more.